# Underline in pdf

Tags: pdf

I was wondering if there was a way to underline in a pdf document.
I have exams this period, and it would be very helpful if I can underline the notes, which are scanned as photos.

Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

[Okular](https://okular.kde.org/) can annotate most pdfs directly, including highlighting and underlining.  It's in the Ubuntu repos.  Another such app is [Xournal](http://xournal.sourceforge.net/), it works well, but creates a secondary file for the annotations.  However, it will work on some files that Okular doesn't work on.

Comment: I think okular is great, but although i can underline on a text that was written on pc, in ascanned photo i cant .Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You would run a scanned document through OCR software, which then creates real text; this text should be annotateable. Otherwise, this OCRd document can be exported to .doc(x), as mentioned in an other answer.

Comment: Xournal will work on bitmaps too. Although with very big files can become sluggish. You can split the file in manageable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well. Here is what you will need to do.

1. Convert the pdf to a doc file [Click here for my search results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#q=convert%20pdf%20to%20word&safe=active&ssui=on)
2. Install Libreoffice or if you have some type of word processing.
3. Find the underline tool.

That is all you really have to do, when your ready libreoffice can convert it back into a pdf

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer.  The problem with that is that i want to load big pdf files(eg 300 pages) ,and the converters(either online or adobe,which i dont have) cant load them or that process takes too much time

Comment: No prob BTW did it work?

Comment: K See your Problem, Try pressing Ctrl A and open a new libre office document and type Ctrl V

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, we are talking about scanned documents, where a simple conversion to .doc(x) would fail without previous OCR…